# ImageView is not showing the youtube thumbnail

Tags: android, listview, imageview, baseadapter

I am new to Android, I am developing an app, where in I search the youtube using the

```
....
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService('blah','blah')
....
VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);
List<VideoEntry> videos = videoFeed.getEntries();

YouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup = videoEntry.getMediaGroup();

String webPlayerUrl = mediaGroup.getPlayer().getUrl();

......                  

ytv.setWebPlayerUrl(webPlayerUrl);

.....

List<String> thumbnails = new LinkedList<String>();
for (MediaThumbnail mediaThumbnail : mediaGroup.getThumbnails()) {

thumbnails.add(mediaThumbnail.getUrl());

}

....
```

In the Adapter, I used this

```
mWebView.loadUrl(torvideo.getWebPlayerUrl());
```

But I get a full screen youtube image in the webview and a scroll able list of similar videos.

However What I want is a thumbnail which looks similar to youtube search result (Small Image, title of the video and few more details.

Can you please suggest me, which view or a sample code, so that I can use the thumbnails list I got it from mediagroup object to display in my app?

Edit/Update:

I have used

```
     public class ResultViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ........

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
    final LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_result_list, null);
    }

TORYouTubeVideo torvideo = (TORYouTubeVideo) getItem(position);

TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(torvideo.getVideoTitle());

    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(torvideo.getThumbnails().get(0)).getContent();

    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    imageView.setImageDrawable(d);

return row;

}
```

But still I cannot see the images in my list view and Only see an empty scrollable list

Thanks

Comment: I have tried to use ImageView with in the listActivity and I don't see the image at all.
....
 InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
     Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
        
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          
          imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(torvideo.getThumbnails().get(0)));

---

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question again!!

Moved this part

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(torvideo.getThumbnails().get(0)).getContent();

Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
```

To the same async task where my youtube query is happening and I am able to see the image now!
(It was the issue with mainThread)

Looks like long way to go with Android!! :P

Thanks